# A coin is tossed until the first time a head turns up.the player wins if n is odd and lose if n is even. find E(x)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A coin is tossed until the **first** time a **head** turns up. 
If this occurs at the **nth** step, then the player wins $\frac{2^n}{n}$ dollars if n is **odd**,and loses  $\frac{2^n}{n}$ dollars if n is **even**. Let X be the amount the player
wins. Find **E(X)** if it exists.

Im a little bit stucked at this question. I understand that X distribute G($\frac{1}{2}$) but I dont know how to refer to the fact that n  can be n even or odd.

thanks for helping

Comment: Is $\frac {2n}n$ different from $2$?

Comment: This particular question is usually asked with $2^n/n$ - I guess you made a typo?

Comment: You are aware that $\frac {2n}n=2$?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: Which implies that you already have a dup at hand...?

Comment: yes I change it now sorry

Comment: @barakmanos Not exactly but this is a problem I came up with for my students a while ago as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Expecation in this particular case

Let's ignore $n$ being either even or odd for a moment and look at the expected value for any $n$. Let $X$ be the profit which can be negative if we lose. The expectation is given using (and assuming the coin is fair)

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left((-1)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{2^n}{n}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{1}{n}.$$

This is the alternating harmonic series which converges to $\log(2)$. **However** the expectation only exists if it converges absolutely **as well**! Looking at

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|(-1)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{2^n}{n}\right|\cdot\frac{1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$$

we notice the harmonic series is divergent hence there is actually no expectation for $X$.

---

### Adjustments to make the expectation exist

Just a sidenote if you're interested: The general harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^\alpha$ does converge for $\alpha>1$; otherwise, it diverges. Therefore changing the game to have a profit of $2^n/n^2$ for example will yield $\mathbb E[X]\neq \infty$ but $\operatorname{Var}[X]=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the first head occurs with the $n$th toss is $2^{-n}$. And in this case the player wins $w(n)=(-1)^{n+1}\cdot \frac {2^n}n$. Hence
$$E(X)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\cdot w(n)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n.$$
You should ecognize the series on the right as some logarithm.

Comment: This is partly true assuming this wasn't just a hint ( :-) ) - you haven't explicitly checked for absolute convergence though, which is necessary for the existence of the expectation.